# How to find recurrence equation of an algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence

We are asked to identify the recurrence equation of a random algorithm in my algorithm analysis class. But the problem is I dont know what to do if there could be 2 different paths in an algorithm.
For example consider:

```
Algorithm foo (A[1...n])
if n=1 return 0;
else if(n%2=0) return 2*foo(A[1....n/3])
else return foo(A[1....n/3])
```

I solved it as,

- T(n)={ 1 , n=1
- 2T(n/3)+1, n=even
- T(n/3)+1,  n=odd }

Then, I calculated the time complexity by using the Master's Theorem as,

- Theta(n^0.630) if n=even
- Theta(1) if n=odd.

I am aware that neither of them is correct, but could you please show me how to determine the time complexity and recurrence equation of a random algorithm?

Comment: There's at most one recursive call, so it's T(1) = 1, T(n) = T(n/3) + 1, T(n) = Theta(log n).